# Deploy Webpart to two Sites in different webcollections

Tags: sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I have two **Webapplications** in Sharepoint 2013 Web1 and Web2.
Web1 has a site collection SP1 and **site1**
Web2 has a site collection SP2 and **site2**.

Site1 has a webpart and I want the same webpart to be deployed on Site2 ,How can I dot it

Answer (score 0):

Export the web part, it will save an XML file to your local drive and then you can choose import webpart in site2 to import the downloaded web part definition.

See here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/sharepoint-foundation-help/manage-and-share-web-parts-HA101794755.aspx#_Toc257985811